# PHPUnit mock request object and extract body and header

Tags: php, phpunit

How do I unit test for my  code which makes http requests . Instead of making actual http call, I want to use mock objects and verify http request has  has correct body and headers set.

Comment: That's too less information. Post the code you want to test and maybe we can say how to test it. First of all you need a code that can receive mocked objects and use them. And by this definition you need to use a class for http requests - example for curl: https://gitlab.w00tserver.org:617/snippets/2

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't contain a lot of information. But for the start I can guide you using this example code.

```
$httpMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Vendor\Path\HttpHandlerYouWantToMock')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->setMethods(['setBody', 'setHeader'])
                 ->getMock();

$httpMock->expects($this->once())
         ->method('setBody')
         ->with($this->identicalTo('{"test":"test"}'));


$httpMock->expects($this->once())
         ->method('setHeader')
         ->with($this->identicalTo('Content-Type: application/json'));

$service = new SomeService($httpMock);
$service->post('/someApi', '{"test":"test"}');
```

This code just in a representation how all should look like but in your case I have no idea what http handler are you using or if this one contain any other services that is dependent on.

So main idea just mock all your services that are used by your own service. And define for this mock what methods you think will be used an what data should be passed there.

And the last use the phpunit documentation https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html